# docker call program (nodejs) from another container (supervisor)

Tags: node.js, docker, supervisord

My docker-compose.yml is like:

```
nodejs:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-nodejs
  tty: true
  ports:
    - "${SOCKET_PORT}:8081"
  volumes:
    - ../node:/var/www/html

supervisor:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-supervisor
  tty: true
  volumes:
    - ..:/var/www/html
    - ./config/supervisor/conf.d:/etc/supervisor/conf.d
  links:
    - nodejs:nodejs
```

And I've created supervisor program config file:

```
[program:nodejs.socket]
command=nodejs /var/www/html/node/server.js
autostart=true
```

**But**: I can't run this program, because supervisor's container

> can't find command 'nodejs'

---

**Question**: Can I actually run nodejs from supervisor-container or I must install supervisor in nodejs-container?

Comment: Isn't the command node?

Comment: By default it is `node`, but I've renamed it in docker-compose.yml file.
Anyway it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: Can I actually run nodejs from supervisor-container or I must install supervisor in nodejs-container?

You must install supervisor in the image that holds nodejs, because supervisor needs to execute nodejs that means to have it as child process.

That is the common way. **However**, you can share the `pid` namespace between two containers, but you will need to have nodejs installed in the same image too. So at that point, that is becoming tricky.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks.